# three way switches not working

Tags: recessed-lighting

I checked the wiring in the ceiling can light. I moved the neutral wires and saw a spark so I twisted it and now the lights work again. But now the three way switches aren't working right. They are more like a two way switch. Do you have any ideas of what I might have done? I did try new switches thinking maybe that was why my lights stopped working in the first place.

Comment: How would we know what you've done? You haven't told us. Seems like checking or reworking all the connections would be prudent.

Comment: Post some pictures of the wiring you worked on .. you might have misconstrued a traveler wire for a neutral wire. Also open both light switches pull the switches out of the box far enough and take pictures. [Turn the CB off before you pull them out , even with CB off you should still work using the one hand rule as if they are live .]  Please also tell us which wires in the pictures you twisted and got sparks ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with what moving wires and twisting "it" (what?) could mean. But I read there was a spark which should put you on alert. Some connection is no longer fixed. Sparks can cause fire! You don't know what's going on there and obviously you don't know how to handle this situation.

Turn off the fuse or breaker or whatever this is called and find a professional to see this ASAP. An electrical expert looking at that is cheaper than a burnt down house.